# An atomic database that supports increments, sorting and update by script

Tags: database, elasticsearch, atomic

I use `ElasticSearch` as a temporary database that calculate values of series of items.

```
POST test/_doc/1/_update
{
    "script" : {
        "source": "ctx._source.views += params.count; ctx._source.impression = 1F * ctx._source.likes / ctx._source.views; ctx._source.value = ctx._source.impression * params.value",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "count" : 1,
            "value" : 600,
        }
    }
}
```

This does 3 things in exact order:

1. adds 1 to `views`
2. calculates `impression` by dividing `likes` by `views`
3. multiplies `impression` by 600 (some number)

And then I can get highest value items by sorting them by value.

Is there any alternative database that can do this?

Edit: It should be able to handle about 2000 updates per second or more.
I don't care if it updates the values with a little latency, I just need it not to miss a single request.

Comment: How about every other database that can do update query.

Comment: name some please. Is mongo able to do that? is it atomic? Does it able to handle more than 2K update per second?